Angular connects styles using a non-existent URL
I have an application with angular and nx stack.
The problem is that when I enter the URL consisting of several parts in the address bar, for example localhost:4200/app/user or localhost:4200/restore/user-id, an error appears:
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/restore/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
When I open the url consisting of a single path, for example, localhost:4200/login, localhost:4200/app everything works.
Apparently, this happens because styles are requested at a non-existent url, for example localhost:4200/restore/styles.css instead of localhost:4200/styles.css
How can this be fixed?

For some reason, everything works fine if I use hash-style routes by passing {useHash: true} as the second parameter to the RouterModule.forRoot(). Any ideas what's happening?

The problem was solved after I added the tag  inside the head tag section of index.html.
